# Insert a new element into an array in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

Code:

```
let oldNums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 , 7, 8, 9, 10]
var newArray = oldNums[1..<4]
newArray.insert(99, atIndex: 0) // <-- crash here
newArray.insert(99, atIndex: 1) // <-- work very well
```

I thank the newArray is a new mutable variable. So I get confuse.
Why? I can't insert a new element into "newArray"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oldNums[1..<4]` is not an array, but an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs10ArraySlice):

> An Array-like type that represents a sub-sequence of any Array, ContiguousArray, or other ArraySlice.

The indices of array slices are not zero-based, but correspond
to the indices of the original array. This is a change that
came with Swift 2 and is documented in the [Xcode 7.0 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-DontLinkElementID_169):

> For consistency and better composition of generic code, ArraySlice
>   indices are no longer always zero-based but map directly onto the
>   indices of the collection they are slicing and maintain that mapping
>   even after mutations.

In your case:

```
let oldNums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var newArray = oldNums[1..<4]
print(newArray.indices)
// 1..<4
```

So `0` is an invalid index for `insert()`, and that's why

```
newArray.insert(99, atIndex: 0)
```

crashes. To insert an element at the beginning of the slice, you 
can use

```
newArray.insert(99, atIndex: newArray.startIndex)
```

To create a "real" array instead of a slice, use the `Array()`
constructor:

```
let oldNums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var newArray = Array(oldNums[1..<4])
print(newArray.indices)
// 0..<3

newArray.insert(99, atIndex:0)
print(newArray)
// [99, 2, 3, 4]
```