# How do I fetch the i'th element from a Swift ArraySlice?

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

Below I am trying to fetch the i'th element of the `ArraySlice` `draggignFan`. The code builds fine (no warnings) but the program dies at runtime on the line where I try to index the slice like a normal array:

```
var draggingFan : ArraySlice<Card>?
...

if let draggingFan = draggingFan {
     for i in 1 ..< draggingFan.count {
         let card = draggingFan[i] // EXECUTION ERROR HERE
         ...
     }
 }
```

According to [the docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/ArraySlice/) there is a `first` and `last` method (which I use elsewhere with no problem). So how do I index an `ArraySlice` in Swift? *(Note: I am intentionally skipping the 0'th index in the slice -- that's needed elsewhere).*

Comment: Probably the same problem as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151581/insert-a-new-element-into-an-array-in-swift.

Comment: Yes. The comment "The indices of array slices are not zero-based" in an answer to that question is the insightful line!

Comment: "Note: I am intentionally skipping the 0'th index in the slice" You're still not listening. The 0th element in the slice is the 0th element in the original. What you mean is the slice's `startIndex`, which is not `0`.

Comment: Yes but this is what we've all been telling you all this time. You just aren't listening.

Comment: Got it @matt -- sorry for being so slow.

Comment: Clarified and neatened up my answer, for posterity if for no one else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indices of the `ArraySlice` still match those of the original array.  In your case, you are accessing index `1` which is not in your slice.  If you offset the index by `draggingFan.startIndex` it will work:

```
if let draggingFan = draggingFan {
     for i in 1 ..< draggingFan.count {
         let card = draggingFan[draggingFan.startIndex + i]
         ...
     }
 }
```

Alternatively:

```
if let draggingFan = draggingFan {
     for i in draggingFan.startIndex + 1 ..< draggingFan.endIndex {
         let card = draggingFan[i]
         ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: He will iterate beyond the end of the slice if he goes from `1` to `draggingFan.count - 1`, but then shifts this by the `startIndex` of the slice.

Comment: @Gavin, I just tried this in a Playground and it works.  The count of the slice is smaller than the count of the original array, so you won't go too far.

Comment: Yes, this was the ticket. Where is the heck is this documented?

Comment: I would avoid using indexes if at all possible. If you iterate directly over the elements you decrease the chances for a bug down the line and your code is more clean. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36458516/887210) below for an example.

Comment: @wcochran, if you Option-click on `ArraySlice` in your code, and then click on `ArraySlice Structure Reference` it will take you to the documentation where it mentions that `startIndex` is the position of the first element.

Comment: @KennethBruno Yes, my answer also gives a good solution, which avoids the need to use the indices of the slice at all! It's completely unnecessary to use the slice indices in this example. If you want to skip the first element, you can see the built-in method that I use in my example to do exactly that. It's called `dropFirst()`, and leads to much cleaner looking and easier to understand code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are having this problem is that the slice maintains the original index numbers of the sequence you got it from. Thus, element 1 is not in this slice.

For example, consider this code:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let slice = arr[2...5]
```

Now what is `slice[1]`? It isn't `4`, even though that is the second thing in the slice. It's `2`, because the slice still points into the original array. In other words, `slice[1]` is out of the slice's range! That is why you're getting a runtime error.

What to do? Well, the actual indexes of the slice are its `indices`. *That* is what you want to cycle thru. But... You don't want the first element pointed to by the slice. So you need to advance the `startIndex` of the range you're going to iterate through. Thus:

```
if let draggingFan = draggingFan {
    var ixs = draggingFan.indices
    ixs.startIndex = ixs.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
    for i in ixs {
        // ... now your code will work ...
    }
}
```

However, in my view, there's no need to index the slice at all, and you shouldn't be doing so. You should cycle through the *slice itself*, not thru its indexes. You have this:

```
for i in 1 ..< draggingFan.count
```

But that is much like saying

```
for aCard in draggingFan
```

...except that you want to drop the first element of the slice. Then drop it! Say this:

```
for aCard in draggingFan.dropFirst()
```

To see that this will work, try this in a playground:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let slice = arr[2...5]
for anInt in slice.dropFirst() {
    print(anInt) // 4, 5, 6
}
```

As you can see, we are cycling through exactly the desired elements, with no reference to index numbers at all.

Comment: No -- I am intentionally skipping the first element in the slice.

Comment: But you shouldn't be. It's the wrong slice. Take a slice of the slice so you have the right slice!

Comment: No -- this was a slice taken at another point in the program and I need the 0'th element for other reasons.

Comment: Look, you haven't explained what you're really doing. I can only answer the tiny piece of the puzzle you actually provided. If you have a real question about how to do some larger thing, you should have asked that. As I've said, you seem to have misunderstood what a slice is; it's not an independent sequence, it's just a window into the original sequence, so its index numbers are dependent on the original sequence. The answer I've given is the elegant way to solve it.

Comment: No -- the question is specific -- how to you fetch the i'th element of a slice.

Comment: And my answer is specific: "ith" doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: Sorry for my impatience. You were telling me the right thing all along.

Comment: @matt Your answer is good but ignores the fact that the OP doesn't even have to deal with the indices of the slice in the first place. He should be iterating over the elements of the slice directly, after dropping the first element of the slice. Take a look at my answer for what I did.

Comment: @matt And yes, I realize the OP says he wanted to fetch the "ith" element of a slice specifically, but his code example says otherwise. This is an example of where the OP was asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Gavin That is just what I said originally, but the OP rejected that. That's why I edited it out of my answer. I'll put it back...

Answer (score 2):

This will access the values from the second element in the slice to the last element in the slice:

```
let original = [1,2,3,4,5,6]        // Int array to demonstrate
var draggingFan : ArraySlice<Int>?
draggingFan = original[1...4]      // create the slice
if let draggingFan = draggingFan {
  // so there's no errors just slice the slice and iterate over it
  for i in draggingFan[(draggingFan.startIndex+1)..<draggingFan.endIndex] {
    print(i, terminator: ", ")
  }
}
```

Output:

> 3, 4, 5,

Comment: Thanks. Good example. Where is this documented?

Comment: Your uses of indices to define your range looks very cluttered and is completely unnecessary. You can drop the first element of a slice without dealing with them. Check out my answer and you'll see a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @wcochran [`ArraySlice` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html) has the methods. At the top it conforms to `CollectionType` which gives it a number of properties and methods and towards the bottom you can see the subscript methods.

Comment: @Gavin I was showing how you could use any range in a slice, the same way you could with an array. Yes, you could just drop the first element but that creates a new Array and could be expensive. That's the idea behind an ArraySlice in the first place, it can just reference the real array and not have to copy the structure.

Comment: After going over the documentation again it does look like `dropFirst()` returns `Self.SubSequence` and not a new `Array`. This is good because that means less copying and less resource-intensive. Thus you could use `for i in draggingFan.dropFirst()` instead of using the longer and more awkward `for i in draggingFan[(draggingFan.startIndex+1)..<draggingFan.endIndex]`

Comment: @KennethBruno Yep, glad you took another look at the documentation. It doesn't create a new array. There's no expensive copying going on. The documentation for `dropFirst()` states that it has complexity of O(1), meaning it's constant time. That's the whole point of slices in Swift, that they very efficiently give you a subsequence of another sequence. That's why using Swift methods as opposed to some more manual solution is usually better, because the Swift team has made sure that things like this operate as efficiently as possible. That's why Swift `struct`s do copy-on-write also.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the elements in the slice:
    draggingFan?.forEach({ (element) 
            ...
    })

As far as I know, the get a specific element, it needs to be converted back to an array e.g.

```
let draggingFanArray = Array(draggingFan!)
```

Here's the playground code I used to toy around with various scenarios:

import Cocoa

```
var a: Array<Int>?
var b: ArraySlice<Int>?

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

b = a![3...5]


let count = b!.count

b!.forEach({ (element) in
    print("\(element)")

})

let c = Array(b!)
print(c[2])
```

*edit* ArraySlice extension though:

```
extension ArraySlice {

    func elementAtIndex(index: Int)->AnyObject?{
        return Array(self)[index] as? AnyObject
    }

}
```

Comment: I am avoiding `forEach` since I am intentionally skipping the first element. This still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Look at the statements after the forEach... Casting it back to an array, then referencing the element.

Comment: Another option is to write an extension ? I'll add a quick and dirty example in my original answer

Comment: @wcochran Like I said in my answer, you can use `forEach` while still skipping the first element. Take a look at it to see how. It's so much cleaner when you use it, and safer too. And Adrian, why the use of optionals for `a` and `b`? You're unnecessarily having to unwrap them after that.

Answer (score 1):

If I have an array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And I take a slice of the array:

```
let slice = arr[3..<arr.count] // [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

This slice will have a `startIndex` of 3, which means that indexing starts at 3 and ends at 6.

Now if I want a slice containing everything but the first element, I can use the `dropFirst()` method:

```
let sliceMinusFirst = slice.dropFirst() // [5, 6, 7]
```

And at this point, `sliceMinusFirst` has a `startIndex` of 4, which means my indexes range from 4 to 6.

Now if I wish to iterate over these to do something with the items, I can do the following:

```
for item in sliceMinusFirst {
    print(item)
}
```

Alternatively, I can do it with `forEach`:

```
sliceMinusFirst.forEach { item in
    print(item)
}
```

By using these forms of iteration, the fact that the `startIndex` is nonzero doesn't even matter, because I don't use the indices directly. And it also doesn't matter that, after taking a slice, I wanted to drop the first item. I was able to do that easily. I could have even done that at the time I wanted to do the iteration:

```
slice.dropFirst().forEach { item in
    print(item)
}
```

Here I dropped the first item from the original slice, without creating any intermediate variables.

Remember that if you need to actually use the index, you're probably doing something wrong. And if you genuinely do need the index, make sure you understand what's going on.

Also if you want to get back to zero-based indexing once you make a slice, you can create an array from your slice:

```
let sliceArray = Array(slice) // [4, 5, 6, 7]
sliceArray.startIndex // 0
```

Comment: Thanks -- that was very insightful. With that said I am going to avoid using slices and just use a normal array -- this is not a performance bottleneck in my code.

Comment: Slices can make your code cleaner. But regardless of what you do, remember that it's not Swift-like to deal with indices directly when it's unnecessary. Remember that `forEach` is your friend. It's always safer to get the slice you want and iterate over the elements than to iterate indices and getting elements from those indices as you go along. It's slower and the code is less clean when you deal directly with indices.

Comment: `dropFirst` is definitely the easiest way to do what you want. Nicely pointed out @Gavin